# Home Server for an iOS developer | Xcode continuous integration

Tags: macos, xcode, mac-mini, osx-server

I am currently developing websites and ios applications. Recently, I decided to install a home server for cloud/back-up purposes and especially for xcode server(helping me test my builds) with version control system.

I also know its possible to install xcode server on your development Mac but im looking for a remote machine.

With mac mini, i will be able to instal OS X Server and get all the services I want.

After days of research I still cant decide whether mac mini late 2014 have all the power i need. Especially in storage wise, I have limited options like 1TB etc. Whereas with other servers available out there, I can find one with more capacity and storage, and i will be able to upgrade it later on.

But I dont really have any upgrade choices with mac mini if i want to later on. So shall I go for a any home server (and give up OS X) or does mac mini can handle my workload and be upgradable?

I am more of a software guy and I really dont understand hardware:/

All the help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A late-model, mid-range  Mini will be fine. If all you need is a personal webserver and compiler farm it's very good value. Probably not powerful enough for rendering 3D animation unless you're patient.

Your storage concerns are very easily eliminated by plugging in an external drive. Get a small SSD with the Mini, store your stuff on a FW800 or Thunderbolt external. note that if you offload your storage to an external there is no point in getting a fusion drive.

Don't forget backups, but do hook up the backup drive via USB2. Simple hardware throttling keeps the backups running at low priority.

I have a 27 inch iMac running Server, it has no problems whatsoever keeping up with the load. I could not do my job as well with a laptop-size monitor but I don't think I'd notice laptop performance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think thunderbolt external will be a great choice in my case. Im glad to hear you have no problems with the server :)